# Why won't my JSF app deploy to GlassFish?

Tags: jsf, netbeans, glassfish

Yesterday I had trouble with my app suddenly failing to deploy from NetBeans to GlassFish server.  I now know why, and am going to answer this question myself.  I just wanted to record this information for the next person that needs it.  I hope the etiquette of that is OK?

Symptom:

1. NetBeans would apparently build the project, not report any compile
   errors, and did show the following line in the output window:
   `Building war: ...`
2. but didn't deploy the app and didn't show the subsequent lines: `---
   maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install ... -SNAPSHOT.war` `Installing
   ... -SNAPSHOT.war`

What was the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a compile error in my code, which didn't show up until I did a complete "Clean and Build" ...and this couldn't be done until I shut-down the GlassFish server.
Conclusion: If the problem occurs try shutting down the GlassFish server and doing a complete "Clean and Build".

Note: I actually first discovered the code error by trying to manually deploy the war using the GlassFish server console, so this is another thing to try.